# Model public method throws CMapIterator warning

Tags: models

I have a strange problem with the following public method on a model.

```
public function getAttributes()
{
    return $this->getId() . $this->getStyle() . $this->getDataAttributes();
}
```

`CMapIterator` warns with the following `array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given`

But if I alter it to

```
public function getAttributes()
{
    return array($this->getId() . $this->getStyle() . $this->getDataAttributes())[0];
}
```

Everybody is happy. It's late and I'm probably shouldn't be coding but any thoughts on the issue would be much appreciated.

Here is the complete model for reference...

```
namespace Craft;

class Core_CodeModel extends BaseModel
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    protected function defineAttributes()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::defineAttributes(), array(
            'cssId' => array(AttributeType::String),
            'cssClass' => array(AttributeType::String),
            'style' => array(AttributeType::String),
            'dataAttributes' => array(AttributeType::Mixed),
        ));
    }

    public function getDataAttributes()
    {
        return is_array($this->dataAttributes) ? ' ' . craft()->core_code->joinDataAttributes($this->dataAttributes) : '';
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return !empty($this->cssId) ? ' id="' . $this->cssId . '"' : '';
    }

    public function getStyle()
    {
        return !empty($this->style) ? ' style="' . str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $this->style) . '"' : '';
    }

    public function getAttributes()
    {
        return $this->getId() . $this->getStyle() . $this->getDataAttributes();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

User error. It's a naming collision with the `getAttributes` method within my model and the `CModel` class.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to know for sure without seeing what's going on in `craft()->core_code->joinDataAttributes` and what type of data is in `$this->dataAttributes`, but my guess is its because you're effectively casting whatever the results of `craft()->core_code->joinDataAttributes` to a string by prepending an space to it here:

```
' '.craft()->core_code->joinDataAttributes($this->dataAttributes)
```

And whatever code is working with that data isn't expecting a string, but an array.

Comment: Thanks brad, but it was actually something a little more silly on my part. I had unintentionally created a conflict with my method names